# What is the | operator used for in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, type-alias, type-declaration

Googling this only returns results to do with the numerical applications of bitwise operators, so I'd like to ask it on SO. I was reading through the @ngrx docs, and I saw this bit of code:

```
export class Increment implements Action {
  readonly type = CounterActionTypes.INCREMENT;
}

export class Decrement implements Action {
  readonly type = CounterActionTypes.DECREMENT;
}

export class Reset implements Action {
  readonly type = CounterActionTypes.RESET;

  constructor(public payload: number) {}
}

export type CounterActionsUnion = Increment | Decrement | Reset;
```

My confusion is in the use of the bitwise OR between classes - I'm sorry if this question sounds juvenile, but why does `Increment | Decrement | Reset` denote a union of the three classes? Thanks!

Comment: It's not JavaScript. It's a `type` declaration. Probably TypeScript. And no, it's not a bitwise operator.

Answer (score 3):

*Credit to @CRice in the 2nd comment of the question for this. I'm just posting it for convenience since s/he didn't.*

> The | character, when used in typescript denotes a [union type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)